# How can i send and recieve data from a table to another table using MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am working in a small `asp.net` MVC4 web project. Here I have three tables: `Attendance`, `Student`, and `Teacher`.

```
Attendance(student_id , Student_Name , Course_Id , Date)
Student(Student_Id,Course_Id,Student_Name)
Teacher(Teacher_Id,Course_Id,Date)
```

The `Attendance` tables stores attendance record comparing the `Student` and `Teacher` table with the id `Course_Id`.

So I want to get data from `Student` and `Teacher` Table and save data to `Attendance` table.

I need help.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see anything that you would be saving in attendance after fetching it from Teacher table.

apart from that, If your are using Entity Framework then You can do in the following way

```
Student student=dbContext.Student.Where(x=>x.Id==studentId).FirstOrDefault();
Attendance attendance=new Attendance();
attendance.Student=student;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```